# Error using PrimeNG component in Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Hey whazzup my (bk) stackerzzz.

I got a real doozy for y'all:

I'm using a `ConfirmDialog` component from the PrimeNG library in my angular 2 app. The component works fine when testing it out in a browser, but for some reason, using the component makes Karma explode.

```
 Error: Error in ./ReturnFileParameterComponent class ReturnFileParameterComponent - inline template:2:4 caused by: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.documentResponsiveListener()') in C:/Users/wlaw/Desktop/ens_fits_ui/karma-shim.js (line 41475)
        ngOnDestroy@C:/Users/wlaw/Desktop/ens_fits_ui/karma-shim.js:71991:45 <- webpack:///~/primeng/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.js:140:0
        ngOnDestroy
        destroyInternal
        destroy@C:/Users/wlaw/Desktop/ens_fits_ui/karma-shim.js:41076:34 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12361:0
        ...
```

In the `component.spec.ts` file, I imported both the dialog service and module needed for the dialog component to work:

```
import {
    ...
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    ConfirmationService
} from 'primeng/primeng';


describe('Return File Parameter Component Test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ReturnFileParameterComponent, HtmlUserFriendlyTimePipe, Html24HourDatePipe, DayOfWeekPipe],
            providers: [
                ...
                ConfirmationService,
                ...
            ],
            imports: [
                ...
                ConfirmDialogModule
            ]
        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
    });

...

    it('should call add on a new Return File Parameter and submit it to the service', inject(
        [ReturnFileParameterComponent, AuthHelper],
        (component: ReturnFileParameterComponent, authHelper: AuthHelper) => {
            let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReturnFileParameterComponent> =
                getTestBed().createComponent(ReturnFileParameterComponent);

            fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit()
                .then(fixture.detectChanges)
                .then(function () {
                    let newParam = fixture.componentInstance.add();
                    expect(fixture.componentInstance.selectedParam).toBe(newParam);
                    expect(fixture.componentInstance.editParam).toBe(true);
                });
        })
    );
});
```

But almost every test fails.

Here is the beginning portion of the template file:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row" id="return-parameter-table">
    <h5>Return File Parameters</h5>
    <p-growl [value]="msgs" life="3000"></p-growl>
    <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>
...
```

So basically I have no idea why its failing the tests but I get absolutely no problems using it in a browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found a workaround. It appears that the `ConfirmDialog` component that is declared by the `ConfirmDialogModule` module has some issues working with Karma/Jasmine. So what I did in the spec was to create a fake `ConfirmDialog` component and override the metadata in the `ConfirmDialogModule` module to look for the fake component instead. The code looks like as follows:

```
// Fake component class because the ConfirmDialog has issues with Karma/Jasmine
@Component({
    selector: 'p-confirmDialog',
    template: ''
})
class FakeConfirmDialogComponent {
}

describe('Return File Parameter Component Test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ReturnFileParameterComponent, HtmlUserFriendlyTimePipe, Html24HourDatePipe, DayOfWeekPipe],
            providers: [
                ...
                ConfirmationService,
                ...
            ],
            imports: [
                ConfirmDialogModule,
                ...
            ]
        });
        TestBed.overrideModule(ConfirmDialogModule, {
            set: {
                declarations: [FakeConfirmDialogComponent],
                exports: [FakeConfirmDialogComponent]
            }
        })
        TestBed.compileComponents();
    });

    // All my tests here
});
```

The key part of this is the `TestBed.overrideModule()` method call, which modifies the metadata of the `ConfirmDialogModule` module.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped.  You're missing a semicolon at the end of ".overrideModule...});"  It's too small a change for me to do, but my linter complained.